# How do I get a list of columns from the Target Data Store in ODI 12 using groovy

Tags: groovy, oracle-data-integrator

I'm looking through packages and classes (https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/odi/reference-java-api/toc.html) and I can't find anything to get a list of columns in my target data store.  Can you please show sample code or point me to a class I should look into?  I'm new to groovy and odi.  Any help would be great.  THANKS!

I'm trying to get a list of columns from the target data store, so I can choose which columns I want to change the expression.

Comment: Please add the code what you tried and what errors you got in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  It is the getColumns() class.